# Move app data to SD

Tags: external-sd, insufficient-memory, data-transfer

I would like to move some of my app's data to the SD card. I am running Android 2.2.1 so I cannot use `Simple2Ext`.

I would also like to avoid `Data2SD` because I've read some bad reviews let alone when I search it on `PlayStore` the responce is tha the application cannot be found.

I have also tried `Link2SD` and `AppMgr III` but those apps don't actualy remove data, as I have read in the [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info)

What can I do to move selectively my app's dat?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- [AppMgr III (App 2 SD)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) - Android 2/3/4
- [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) - Android 1.6+

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have already tried those two apps, but they can't remove data;they move just the `apk`, as I have read at the [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove data of an app: go to settings, apps (or app manager), tap on the app, scroll down, press "remove data"

Comment: That's a good answer, but I think the OP wants to move the app's data directory to the SD card, rather than just clearing the existing data.

Comment: Yeah, there's a tiny little difference between "re: moving data" and "removing data" :)